# Does VelocityJS has some "from" method like TweenMax?

Tags: javascript, gsap, velocity.js

In TweenMax i can do this:

```
TweenMax.from(block,3,{x:500,y:500});
```

To animate , in this case, to the original position (i hope i am being clear enough, but im sure that anybody that uses TweenMax knows what 'from' does at difference with the 'to').

How can achieve this same using VelocityJS?

Sorry if my question is maybe to naive, but i can't find how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't think there is an equivalent of **[`.from()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/from/)** method of **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax)** in **[VelocityJS](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)** that I am aware of. as **@ydaniv** suggested, either set values in your CSS directly or set using jQuery's **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** just before executing VelocityJS animation.

Comment: I don't think there's specific problem with the question, it can still serve as reference for people coming from a GSAP background to Velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an actual corresponding method in Velocity that does that, so the best way to achieve this effect would be to set an element to its initial state in your CSS, and then animate it to its final state, along with [force-feeding](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#forcefeeding) for best performance. Example:

In your CSS:

```
#block { transform: translateX(100%); }
```

And in JS:

```
Velocity(document.getElementById('block'), { translateX: [0, '100%'] });
```